# How to test my application on older version of IE?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have installed IE8 on my system. I usually test my application on this browser, but the problem arises when i got to know that the client is using IE7. Now how can i test my application on IE7?

One possible solution is to have dual booting on my system. So on version of Windows i can have IE7 and on another i can have IE8. But i really don't want to use this solution.

Another possible solution is to use PC Emulator [ Don't know what is this, just heard about these ]. Using which i can have multiple IE version simultaneously. Have you ever tried this solution? Please name any good **FREE** emulator.

Please let me know if there is any other better solution.

Comment: Take a look at this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541225/cross-browser-testing-all-major-browsers-on-one-machine

Comment: See my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541225/cross-browser-testing-all-major-browsers-on-one-machine#comment48337272_10541484

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

and here can you see all browser versions as picture

http://browsershots.org/

Answer (score 6):

I got the solution. :)

*In IE8, click on Tools > Developer Tools | or press F12*

[image]

*Then in developer Tools > select the browser mode [ available: IE7, IE8, IE8 with compatibility view ]*

[image]

This is what i was expecting. :)

Comment: This might not be accurate.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft provides a [free set of Windows Virtual PC images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) for testing various versions of IE on various Windows service packs.

[Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/support/virtual-pc-2007.aspx) is also free.

Comment: but you have to have a compatible processor with virtualization support

Comment: you must have extra windows licences for do this. also it is not free

Comment: @drorhan - I don't believe that a license is required - the images expire (either on a set date or 120 days after activation) and are treated as demo versions. Virtual PC is a free download from the MS site. However, I can't find documentation to confirm this conclusively. Do you have links to any documentation to support your view?

Comment: i mean windows license not VPC. sorry for missunderstand

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever seen [Microsoft Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx) tool? It contains kick-ass tool for testing pages in various versions of IE - SuperPreview. And this tool also available free, you can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677&displaylang=en).
It's much more easy to use it instead of Virtual PC images. But it can't replace VPC completely because testing in clear environment is also very important.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick and easy web service solution, good for quick testing. 
http://www.browserstack.com/

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking for an answer here's a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en)
It has over 6 millions users, and it claims:

> Top 10 Chrome extension since 2009!
>
> -- WINDOWS ONLY -- WINDOWS ONLY --
>
> IE Tab exactly emulates IE by using the IE rendering engine directly
>   within Chrome.  This will enable you to use ActiveX controls and test
>   your web pages with different versions of IE (IE6, IE7, IE8, or IE9).
>
> -- FEATURES --
>
> - Create a list of URLs that will automatically open in IE Tab
> - Group Policy support for enterprise deployments
> - Securely use the old IE rendering engine
> - Edit Sharepoint documents instead of opening read-only
> - Use Java, Silverlight, and ActiveX in Chrome seamlessly

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at Adobe BrowserLab:

http://browserlab.adobe.com

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has launched Modern.IE to help with this.  Go here to download a test image for your preferred OS and visualization software.

http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads