# How to check if socket.io is compatible with browser?

Tags: node.js, cross-browser, socket.io

The socket.io website says it's pretty much compatible with all browswers [cross browser compatibility](http://socket.io/#browser-support).
How can I programmatically check if socket.io is compatible with the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you'll have to try separate tools for each browser...

I was about to type out a bunch of tools I've used in the past, but then I found this awesome post which notes most of the good ways to test browser compatibility...go that guy.

[Cross Browser Testing - One Answer to Rule Them All](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541225/cross-browser-testing-all-major-browsers-on-one-machine)